# SMS reading app withs HTTPS URL

Tags: android, https

I am looking for an Android SMS reading app in which I could provide a HTTPS URL.

And when the mobile received an SMS it posts to the HTTPS URL.

Comment: Those are called [SMS Forwarder](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage#group_82). Make your pick – and be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then (I'm not using any of those myself, so I cannot recommend one of the candidates behind my link – which, disclosure, goes to my Android app listings).

Answer (score 1):

[SMS to URL forwarder](https://github.com/bogkonstantin/android_income_sms_gateway_webhook) Android app can do this.

P.S. I am the author.

Comment: It is customary to mention that you are the author :-) Upvote, this looks like a very good app and should do what OP asks for